# Cannot click a button using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to loop through an array to search and add multiple items in cart in https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/search/
However, after the search the add to cart button simply does not work from Puppetteer. I have tried several ways like using xpath, text, classname and none of them seem to work.

```
            const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., ' Add to cart ')]");
            if (button) {
                await button.click();
            }

            const buttons = await page.$$('button[class*="cartControls-addButton"]')
            .then(()=>console.log("got buttons"))
            console.log(buttons);
            await buttons[i].click();
            
            let button = await page.$x('//*[@id="search-content"]/div/wow-product-search-container/shared-grid/div/div[1]/shared-product-tile/section/footer/div/shared-cart-controls/div/shared-cart-buttons/div/div/div/div/button/span')
            console.log(button);
            
            const linkHandlers = await page.$x("//a[contains(text(), ' Add to cart ')]");

            if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
              await linkHandlers[0].click();
            } else {
              throw new Error("Link not found");
            }
```

Can you please let me know what my issue is? I also have all of my code in [this repo](https://github.com/sandes93/Woolies) .

Comment: I don't see an array here. Can you share a [mcve]? Can you elaborate on "not working"? Is there an error message, unusual behavior, other details? Thanks.

Comment: I could not format the code in the comment properly. I have added a snippet of the code for my issue and the HTML of the button in [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/jwn5y6x2/). The buttons variable is undefined and i am trying to have puppeteer click on the button in any way possible.